# String method cannot be found in a main class method

Tags: java, string, class, methods, program-entry-point

I have about a one year experience programming Java, I made a static method located in the main class, and for some reason, whenever I compile it gives me an error saying that the compareTo() method from the String class can't be found.

Here's the method:

```
 public static void displaySpecificResort(String resortName, Resort[] resortList)  
  {
     int low = 0;
     int high = resortList.length - 1;
     int mid;
     while (low <= high)
     {
        mid = low + (high - low);
        if (resortList[mid].compareTo(resortName)<0) 
           low = mid + 1;
        else if (resortList[mid].compareTo(resortName)>0) 
           high = mid - 1;      
        else resortList[mid].display(); 
     }
     if(resortList[mid].getName().compareTo(resortName)!= 0)
        System.out.println("Resort could not be found.");
  }
```

Here's the error it gives me when I try and compile:

```
ResortOrganizer.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
        if (resortList[mid].compareTo(resortName)<0) 
                           ^
```

symbol:   method compareTo(String)
  location: class Resort

```
ResortOrganizer.java:159: error: cannot find symbol
        else if (resortList[mid].compareTo(resortName)>0) 
                                ^
```

symbol:   method compareTo(String)
  location: class Resort

2 errors

Can someone explain why it does this? I have a feeling I'm forgetting something important.

Comment: Show us your `Resort` class and we can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Your mid is just `mid = high`, perhaps you meant `mid = low + (high - low)/2;` or `mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem like your `Resort` method doesn't declare a `compareTo` method. This method typically belongs to the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Make sure your class implements it.

Additionally, the `compareTo` method is typically implemented as accepting an argument of the same type as the object the method gets invoked on. As such, you shouldn't be passing a `String` argument, but rather a `Resort`.

Alternatively, you can compare the names of the resorts. For example

```
if (resortList[mid].getResortName().compareTo(resortName)>0)
```

Comment: Ah! how silly, I forgot to use the getter method from my Resort class to compare the string field inside my Resort object to the Argument. That fixed it, it seems. Thanks for answering!